# Hermit reasoning inconsistency checking and memory consumption

Tags: owl, protege, hermit

I use Hermit via Protege to check the consistency of my OWL model. However, it seems that the ontologies that I import in my model, lead to failure due to lack of memory. I run on a 16GB RAM PC and even when I use `Xmx14500M -Xms14000M` parameters for java heap, the reasoning process fails due to memory size, while showing the "Building class hierarchy..." message.

Questions:

1. I understand that (at least sometimes) when my model is inconsistent, these inconsistency errors are raised relatively early (e.g. in the first 3-4 minutes), before the "Building class Hierarchy..."
   message. I cannot really confirm that this happens every time. Is it safe to assume that Hermit checks for inconsistencies first and then tries to construct the model's inferred class hierarchy? If this is true, when I reach the "Building class hierarchy..." message, it means that my model is consistent. Is this true?
2. While the inferred relationships (e.g. the inferred class hierarchy) could be useful in my use case, checking the consistency of my model is my priority. Could I somehow instruct Hermit to only check for inconsistencies and not try to build the requested class hierarchy?
3. Can I do something to increase performance? Apart from increasing the java heap size, is there any kind of customization that could be useful?
4. Would other reasoners typically behave better regarding memory consumption? Should I try another alternative?

Please note that I use Hermit reasoner 1.3.8.413 via Protege 5.2

Comment: 1.) yes, without an consistent ontology, computing the class hierarchy wouldn't make any sense. 2.) settings -> reasoner 3.) no, complexity is inherent in the ontology + the reasoning algorithm. 4.) you should for sure try Pellet reasoner

Comment: @AKSW thank you very much. You should have post it as an answer in order for me to accept it.